# How to use replace double backslashes to single one for byte string in Python

Tags: python, byte

I want to replace double backslashes to single one for byte string in Python.

For example, 
there is a bytes string.

```
word = b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\\r\xca\xe6m'
```

I need this bytes string.

```
word = b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\r\xca\xe6m'
```

If I use replace like:

```
word = word.replace(b"\\",b"\")
```

I got this error.

```
File "test.py", line 79
word = word.replace(b"\\", b"\")
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: use word = word.replace(b"\\\\", b"\\")

Comment: It doesn't work , I got same string.

Comment: b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\\r\xca\xe6m' has only one slash before r. print it and see. Since \ is special character it is escaped using \\ .

Comment: If I use word = word.replace(b"\\r", b"\r"), I got word = b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\r\xca\xe6m'. I want to do same thing from "//" to "/"

Answer (score 6):

`\\` is not double backslash but one escaped. Look:

```
print b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\\r\xca\xe6m'
# Z���jq\r��m
```

And `\r` (from your desired output) is not 2 chars but one:

```
print b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\r\xca\xe6m'
# ��m�jq
```

(When printing it to terminal, [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) `\r` prevents us from seen the first letter `Z`)

If you **really** want to replace `'\\r'` with `'\r'`, you can do:

```
print repr(word.replace('\\r', '\r'))
# 'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\r\xca\xe6m'
print word.replace('\\r', '\r')
# ��m�jq
```

Or, if you want to replace all the [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). Python2 version:

```
print repr(b'1\\t2\\n3'.decode('string_escape'))
# '1\t2\n3'
print b'1\\t2\\n3'.decode('string_escape')
# 1 2
# 3
```

Python3 version:

```
print(repr(b'1\\t2\\n3'.decode('unicode_escape')))
# '1\t2\n3'
print(b'1\\t2\\n3'.decode('unicode_escape'))
# 1 2
# 3
```

Comment: If I want to replace all escape characters like \\r, \\n, \\Z, .. to \r, \n, \Z .... How can I do that?

Comment: @AtsushiSakai Updated my answer.

Comment: I got an error...     print(repr('1\\t2\\n3'.decode('string_escape')))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Also, it is not bytes, str. I need the version of bytes.

Comment: @AtsushiSakai You are right, python2 and python3 syntaxes differ here. Updated once more.

Answer (score 1):

your `\r` is a carriage return character. So `\\r` is `\` plus carriage return. You won't find `\\` in your string.

What "works" is to replace backslash+CR by just CR:

```
word = b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\\r\xca\xe6m'

print(word.replace(b"\\r",b"\r"))
```

result:

```
b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\r\xca\xe6m'
```

but I'm not sure that's what you meant from the start (that is: inserting a carriage return char in your bytes string)

Comment: I want to replace all escape characters like \\r, \\n, \\Z, .. to \r, \n, \Z ....

Answer (score 0):

You have a byte stream.
You need to escape '\' and decode bytes.

```
word = b'Z\xa6\x97\x86j2\x08q\\r\xca\xe6m'
new_word = (str(word).encode('utf-8'))
print(new_word.replace(b"\\\\",b"\\").decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: can you decode to utf-8 and check results.
word = word.replace(b"\\\\",b"\\").decode("utf-8")

Comment: I got an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: I hope my new edit will solve your problem. I tried and it works for me