# How to replace double backslash to single backslash

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

many of the findings are for python2, my case is python3:

I need to replace double back slash to single back slash

`a = 'RXIE-SERVER\\MSSQLSERVER_NEW'`

An "accepted answer" from this post [python3 replacing double backslash with single backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199840/python3-replacing-double-backslash-with-single-backslash) doesn't work here:

[image]

So what is the problem here? Thank you very much.

**[UPDATE]:**

Thanks to @ShadowRanger's reply, so if print the string after the replace operation, it is working expected, however, in my case I need to concat the post-replacement to generate another variable (conn_str), as you can see, it is still showing double backslash.

Any clue for a workaround?

Thank you very much.

```
server = str.replace(data['server'], "\\\\", "\\")
database = data['database']
driver = data['driver']
auth = data['auth']

conn_str = "DRIVER={" + driver + "}; SERVER=" + server + "; Database=" + database + ";" + auth
```

[image]

Comment: Similar question, not quite a duplicate: [How to use replace double backslashes to single one for byte string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51210485/4518341)

Comment: Thanks. That post was very confusing, not well explained to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 'RXIE-SERVER\\MSSQLSERVER_NEW'
```

doesn't have a double backslash. It has an escaped single backslash, it's just safer (and will eventually be required) to escape it so Python doesn't think `\M` is an attempt at a string escape. If you do:

```
print(a)
```

you'll see it only prints one backslash (because `print` outputs the raw data without showing escapes).

The reason `a.replace('\\', '')` doesn't work is because it replaced the single backslash with nothing (and it would do so for all backslashes); `a.replace('\\\\', '\\')` doesn't work because `'\\\\'` represents the actual doubled backslash, and you don't have any of those.

If your input came from some other source (not the literal you described) and *actually* has a doubled-backslash, then `a.replace('\\\\', '\\')` actually worked, but REPL's echo the `repr` of the object, and for `str`, that means adding the backslash escape to make it a legal, equivalent `str` literal, so it *looked* like a double-backslash, but only had one. If you change `>>> a.replace('\\\\', '\\')` to `>>> print(a.replace('\\\\', '\\'))` (which prints the human-friendly form, not the `repr`), you'll see it display only a single backslash.

If you don't like how it looks in your code, use raw strings to remove the need for the escape:

```
a = r'RXIE-SERVER\MSSQLSERVER_NEW'
#   ^ note prefix that makes it raw
```

Comment: Thank you, but sorry the original string is generated from somewhere else, I do need to find a way to replace the double backslash into single backslash.

Comment: @mdivk: If it actually has a double-backslash, then the `a.replace('\\\\', '\\')` code actually worked. You just didn't think it did, because the REPL's echoing functionality echoes the `repr` of the object, which would display the resulting single backslash as a double backslash (because it's intended to be a legal `str` literal, which would need the extra backslash as an escape). Change `>>> a.replace('\\\\', '\\')` to `>>> print(a.replace('\\\\', '\\'))` and you'll see it's really only one backslash.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger, yes, I thought it was not done, but actually it did. I've made some update to my OP, still not what needed.

Comment: @mdivk: Yes, it is what you needed. You're looking at the `repr` again; Python doesn't magically add a slash back in. Just use it, you'll find it behaves exactly as you expect it to.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I will end up of a connection string that contains a non-recognized server `RXIE-SERVER\\MSSQLSERVER_NEW`, and I have to manually create a connection string with `RXIE-SERVER\MSSQLSERVER_NEW` , thanks.

Comment: @mdivk: You performed the replace. It's done. If `print(server)` shows one backslash, so will `print(conn_str)`.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger.